# matchit matches tags, but does not highlight

Tags: plugin-matchit

In my fortran, ftplugin, I have added
`packadd matchit`, which matched `do/end do` tags and `%` do jump from beginning to end. But it doesnot highlight the lines. Is there an easy way of doing it?  I mean I dont want to install matchup or other plugins for this seemingly minor task.

[image]

I am expecting a highlight as I get here with if block.

Comment: I believe matchparen is responsible for highlighting brackets; there's also `'showmatch'`. But what do you mean "does not highlight the lines"? Could you give an example of what you want?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: I am expecting, the matching line should be highlighted, when matchit gets its match "b:match_words". By highlight, I obviously mean the matching lines will be highleghted, with different guifg/guibg.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: a screenshot of my expectation is attached. So, what I meant to say, as my cursor in on any of the line of %(if, else, endif here), all the lines will be highlighted.